# GNU parallel - keep output colored

Tags: colors, gnu-parallel

I'm parallelizing some 0-args commands (scripts/whatever) which have colored outputs, but when parallel prints the output it's colorless (unless I use the `-u` option, but then it's unordered).

Is there a way to change that?

The line I'm using (illustration):

```
echo "script1 script2 script3" | tr " " "\n" | parallel -j3 'echo {}":\n\n"; eval {}'
```

BTW, I'm using a local version of GNU parallel, but it's supposed to be more or less the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that your commandline tools detect that they are not printing to a terminal (GNU Parallel saves into temporary files before printing them to the terminal). Some tools you can force colors even if the output is to a file:

```
parallel 'echo {} | grep --color=always o' ::: joe
```

You can ask GNU Parallel to give the script the tty:

```
parallel --tty -j+0 'echo {} | grep o' ::: joe
```

`--tty` defaults to `-j1` so you have to explicitly override that. It also has problem, that GNU Parallel cannot kill the jobs. This will run for 10 sec:

```
parallel --tty --timeout 5 sleep ::: 10
```

Comment: You mean that the scripts are responsible for the colorless output? i.e there's an explicit piece of code there that detects the redirection to a file and disable colors? and otherwise it would come out colorful?

Comment: @elad Yes. They will test if the output is a tty.

Comment: How to display colors and group outputs? I'm not able to use `--tty` and `--group` without losing color.

Comment: @NicolasBoisteault I do not think you can. `--group` redirects output into temporary files. If your program tests if output is redirected to a file, and therefore refuses to output colors, I do not see a way to avoid this. You would have to somehow make the program think, that it is outputting to a tty. You might be able to trick your program using `script`. If you find a general solution, I would love to know: Maybe `--tty` could be extended with that.